# URL Rewrite Rule: HTTP to HTTPS Not Working in IIS 8 2016 Server: ERR_INVALID_REDIRECT

Tags: iis-8

I installed a godaddy SSL certificate. All these urls work in the browser: 
"park.mydomain.com", "http://park.mydomain.com", "https://park.mydomain.com". The first two show unsecured and the last secured. In the bindings I have two entries. One [https park.mydomain.com port 443] and the other is [http park.mydomain.com port 80]. I installed URL rewrite and added a rule from this link:  [here](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9953/38/iis-redirect-http-to-https). Now, if I type the first or the second url the browser says not found ERR_INVALID_REDIRECT. Only the third one that is https:park.mydomain.com works. If I disable the rule all three work again. What is wrong ? Why is it not redirecting ? The 2016 server with IIS is hosted in azure

```
   <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="http_https" enabled="false" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_POST}/{R:1}" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Comment: Could you pleae post the details rule about your rewrite rule. You could find it in your server web.config file's rewrtie tag.

Answer (score 0):

The redirection was setup correctly. The problem was on the type of certificate that I had installed, that was for one domain only.